# Sailsjs Model.update not working in controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Just a quick beginner question...

Are controllers allowed to perform updates in Sails? I know the action routes do, however I can not get code like this to update.

```
//controller code (this DOES NOT update)

Packets.update({packet:5},{cron:'locationhistory'})
.then( function(r){
        console.log(r);
    });
```

This process works, so I'm confused why the above will not.

```
//controller code that does work, however I'm calling a custom function
sails.models.packets.updateMyPacket('locationhistory', 9, function( response ){
        console.log(response);
    });

// model code
updateMyPacket: function( p, num, cb) {
Packets.update({ cron: p}, {packet: num}).then( function( packets){
    cb(packets);
});
```

}

Can anybody help? What am I missing?

thanks
Matt

Comment: are you getting any type of error that you can share?

Comment: no errors at all, just doesn't update. That is why I'm stumped. I'm using mongo, not that it matters, but even when try to do it by id, I have no luck there either.

Comment: Hey @Matt just to let you know Sails.js does have a Gitter page in case you're interested.I've found some help there, and I'm very new to coding. [Gitter](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails)

Comment: Thanks Joe. I'm checking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have your Criteria and your Values swapped between the two different approaches.

Comment: You're exactly right, I modified that and it works. Do you know why it matters? Clearly accidental, however nice to know but I need to understand what the underlying rules might be. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The first argument is the criteria that limits what gets updated. So in your first example you're updating `cron === `locationhistory`` on every record where with `packet = 5`. When you switch that you are updating `packet=5` on every record where `cron === 'locationhistory'` check out https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-methods.md#update-search-criteria--values--callback-

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update a document, you have to use the set() function.

Pets.update({id:1}).set({id:2})

So now that document have the id:2, when before had id:1